# Displaying snackbar with no internet connection constantly like instagram

Tags: flutter

I want to display snackbar with label "no internet connection", constantly when we load new data and my internet connection is off similarly like we see in Instagram, when internet connection is off. Now i am able to display the snackbar only one time but I want to display constantly for some interval of time when we load new data.

I implemented the functionality to monitor the internet connection but i am able to show snackbar only one time when I off the internet connection.but i want to show it everytime when we load the data similarly like instagram.

Comment: Can you share any snippets of how did you implement monitoring internet connectivity continuously and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In your `SnackBar`, you can specify a duration to make it "permanent." Try something like the following:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  const SnackBar(
    duration: Duration(days: 365),
    content: Text('No internet connection.'),
  ),
);
```

Then, when the internet connection is online again, you can remove the `SnackBar` with [`removeCurrentSnackBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessengerState/removeCurrentSnackBar.html):

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
```

Full code example:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=4b93631b528ad26d2c162caa5a482700

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Permanent SnackBar Example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatelessWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                duration: Duration(days: 365),
                content: Text('No internet connection.'),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
          },
          child: const Text('Hide SnackBar'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to display the snackbar permanently it should display for some few seconds, when we load the data and my internet connection is off. Like we see in Instagram. I want to implement the same functionality that instagram has for monitoring the internet connection and showing the snackbar.